# Looking for function generator or app which will stream / cast audio

Tags: tone

I would like a sound tone generator or a function generator, that I can cast to a device.

My specific need is to hook up a tone generator to systems, without a wired connection.

Ideally a audio function generator app, which can cast, would be desirable because anyone could use it, and there would be no special hardware or wiring.

Because I will want to change frequency real time, a youtube recording would not work.

Does anyone know of an app which is a function or tone generator and will cast?

Answer (score 2):

There is a website that can help - https://www.szynalski.com/tone-generator/ . As long as your computer can send audio wirelessly. You can change frequencies on the fly (and even punch in precise frequencies), select four waveforms (sine, saw, square, and triangle), and quickly double/half the frequency

Comment: yeah nice one that works a treat.

Comment: Glad I can help!

Answer (score 0):

It'll be easier to split those functions: one application to generate the tones, and another that will cast computer audio in your preferred protocol.

Comment: @dont_copy_that_floppy already got it. Browser does the casting, webaudio app does the tone generation.